# LocalDateTime en Springnboot parametro no funciona

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring

Estoy intentando desesperadamente que pasando un LocalDate desde la URL (http://localhost:9000/fechas/enero?date=01-01-2022) vaya hacia el controlador y luego al servicio, pero sigue saliendome esto todo el rato:

> 2023-10-15T19:05:44.361+02:00  WARN 24936 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value [01-01-2022]]

```
    public String daysSinceJanuary (@RequestParam("date") 
                                    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) 
                                    LocalDateTime date, Model model){
    fechasService.daysSinceJanuary(date, model);
    return "fechas";
```

Servicio:

```
 public String daysSinceJanuary(@RequestParam("date") 
                                @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) 
                                LocalDateTime date, Model model){{
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        //probaremos usar el método first day of year para agilizar
        LocalDateTime firstDay = now.with(firstDayOfYear());
        System.out.println(firstDay);
        String daysInBetween;
        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDay, date);
        daysInBetween = "Han pasado " + (int)days + " días";
        model.addAttribute("daysInBetween", daysInBetween);
        return daysInBetween;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner DateTypeFormat.ISO.DATE en lugar de DATE_TIME? Según el [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html) DATE_TIME incluye horas, minutos etc. Por otro lado en el mismo javadoc te indica que ese formato es yyyy-MM-dd, es decir, espera el año al principio, y no como lo estás pasando tú